# Search model is getting cleared for second page request in PagedList.MVC in MVC

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, paging, pagedlist

I am using PagedList.MVC for paging in my MVC application.So first i am on home page and when i fill search bar and submit the form it post the Model on search method , which is as bellow.

```
public ActionResult GetSearchdProperty(int? page,SearchModel objSearch)
{
        var objProperty =  db.re_advertise.OrderBy(r => r.id);
        return View("SearchedProperty", objProperty.ToPagedList(pageNumber: page ?? 1,pageSize: 2));
}
```

So this redirect to search page with searched criteria results. Now when i click 2nd page of PagedList.MVC paging same method is called but at this time i am getting my SearchModel Empty or say blank BUT I want my search model as is on all page request when going from paging. So how can i achieve this?

I have tried taking search model in `VieBag` but i am not getting on how to send model from view bag in paging request. I dont know how can i pass model in `Html.PagedListPager`

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("GetSearchdProperty", "SearchProperty", new { page })).
```

> EDIT

```
public class SearchModel
    {
        public string search_text { get; set; }
        public string min_area { get; set; }
        public string max_area { get; set; }
        public string min_price { get; set; }
        public string max_price { get; set; }
        public string bedroom { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You should be returning a view model containing your search/filter properties and a property for `IPagedList<T>` Then add the values to the url, for example `new { page, searchText = Model.SearchText, fllter = Model.Filter, ..... }`

Comment: Is performance is degraded if i have lots of field in search and i pass all value as method suggested by you? And can i get all value in model at controller side?

Comment: No and Yes (but what is your `SearchModel`?)

Comment: SearchModel is my custom model for search fields it containn 6 fields of searchbar

Comment: I meant, you should include it in the question :)

Comment: Suggest you add `public IPagedList<yourModel> { get; set; } to `SearchModel` (and see first comment)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! @Stephen Muecke I got it working as suggested by your method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a property to your view model for the `IPagedList<T>` and then return your model, so the search/filter values can be added to the url

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string search_text { get; set; }
    public string min_area { get; set; }
    ....
    IPagedList<yourModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GetSearchdProperty(int? page, SearchModel model)
{
    model.Items = db.re_advertise.OrderBy(r => r.id).ToPagedList(pageNumber: page ?? 1,pageSize: 2));
    return View("SearchedProperty", model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model SearchModel
....
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("GetSearchdProperty", "SearchProperty", 
    new { page, search_text = Model.search_text, min_area = Model.min_area, .... }))
```