# ASP.NET MVC multiple parameters and models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, parameter-passing

**Description**: I have a model `WorkOrder` which contains `WorkOrderForm` model (`start_date, end_date, organization`), a list of models (the actual orders) and page parameters (`page, page_size, page_count`). The main idea is to display work orders, and because there is a large amount of them I have to filter the data; work orders get pulled from a database server (not local). On the initial View i prompt for `start_date` and `end_date`, I use `DataType.Date` and for `organization` i use `string`, this information get's stored in the model which I then pass in to the `HttpPost`. It extracts the data and displays it. Now, because there is A LOT of orders, I made costume pages to sort data, and I use 2 variables, `page` and `page_size`, which are displayed and can be set on the view after a valid `WorkOrderForm` was submitted.

**Problem**: The problem I am facing right now is that I can't seem to pass the 2 parameters `page` and `page_size`, from the view back to the controller at the same time. Both of them work but seem to reset each other, Example: I am on `page` 4, set `page_size` from 20 to 50, and it resets `page` to 1, this one is alright, but the main on is when I chose a `page`, it will reset the `page_size` to default (20). All the submitting has to happen inside Html.BeginForm() otherwise i lose the information stored in my model.

**EDIT:** now using PagedList.

**New Problem**: when I select a page it calls the `[httpget]`, resetting the model and page size. I tried to implement it all in the Index, but failed miserably.

WorkOrder:

```
 public class WorkOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IPagedList<mymodel> view_list { get; set; }
    public WorkOrderForm work_form { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(WorkOrder model)
    {
        var list = new List<mymodel>();
        model.view_list = list.ToPagedList(1,1);
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(WorkOrder model, int? page, int? page_size, string start_date, string end_date, string org)
    {
        var list = new List<mymodel>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (OracleDbctx ctx = new OracleDbctx())
            {
                //database stuff

                int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
                int pageSize = (page_size ?? 20);


                model.view_list = list.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

                return View(model);
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect Information submitted");
        return View();
    }
```

Page Info submission in my view:

```
 @:Page @(Model.view_list.PageCount < Model.view_list.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.view_list.PageNumber) of @Model.view_list.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.view_list, page => Url.Action("Index", "WorkOrder",
            new { page, ViewBag.page_size, start_date = Model.work_form.start_date, end_date = Model.work_form.end_date, org = Model.work_form.org }));
```

**Question**: How do I go about passing both of the parameters from the view and at the same time keep my model information, even if i am only choosing to update 1 parameter? If you have suggestions on possible work around's I would be happy to hear some ideas, even pointing me in a direction would be appreciated. If there might be something I am missing please do say.

**New Question**: How to ether get PagedList to call the [httppost] Index, or whats the best way to implement something like this in the default Index controller?

Comment: Your buttons will only pass the value of their `name` attribute, not the values of other buttons. You already have a model with `page_size` and `page_count` so bind form controls to them (e.g, a dropdownlist or radio buttons for `pages_size`) and have one submit button (and remove the `page` and `page_size` parameters from the method

Comment: Multiple submit buttons in a form usually discouraged, a `DropDownListFor` (DDLF) to let user choose page size considered better. Buttons to select a page can be substituted with dynamically generated `ActionLink`s or another DDLF bound for `page` property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you elaborate please? I am not sure how to implement that.

Comment: The code to handle this properly is far too to include here. I recommend you consider using a package such as PagedList.MVC - [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I describe that when I use PagedList it doesn't carry over my model information, I am not sure how to make it so when I change the page, the information the model contains in the view is reused.

Comment: Then your not implementing it correctly. Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551527/search-model-is-getting-cleared-for-second-page-request-in-pagedlist-mvc-in-mvc/38558692#38558692) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985561/how-do-i-add-a-model-dropdown-in-a-ipagedlist-model/32986109#32986109) for a some examples

Comment: Alright so I went and tried some of your solutions out, and I run in to a variety of problems. If i don't use HttpPost, I get all sorts of bugs with the model. And when I use PagedListPager, it takes me to my default Index, which i use to ask the user to fill out the model. I also sacrifice my Datatype.Data

Comment: Then your not doing it correctly. Ask a new question with the code you have tried and we will be able to fix it for you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following implementation of the Index in the Controller worked

```
public ActionResult Index(WorkOrder model, int? page, int? page_size, string start_date, string end_date, string org)
        {
            if (model.work_form == null)
            {
                if (start_date != null && end_date != null && org != null)
                {
                    var form = new WorkOrderForm
                    {
                        start_date = start_date,
                        end_date = end_date,
                        org = org
                    };
                    model.work_form = form;
                }
            }

            if (model.work_form != null)
            {
                using (OracleDbctx ctx = new OracleDbctx())
                {
                    //do database stuff
                    //var list = database(query).ToList()

                    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
                    int pageSize = (page_size ?? 20);
                    int count = list.Count;
                    if (pageNumber - 1 > count / page_size)
                    {
                        pageNumber = 1;
                    }


                    model.view_list = list.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```